# Color specific cell in an xlsx with python

Tags: python, excel

Hello all (excuse me for my bad English), I want to color cell in an xlsx doc in terms of value.

Here's an example.

[image: An snapshot of an Excel table showing example data]

I want to color all the "Alexandre".

For that I create this:

```
path_to_excel="doc.xlsx"
exemple=openpyxl.load_workbook(path_to_excel)


ws = exemple['Sheet1'] #Name of the working sheet

from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

#on définie la couleur de coloriage en hexa
Ok_couleur = PatternFill(patternType='solid', 
                            fgColor='94e0de')

for column in ws['B']:
        if column.value == "Alexandre":
            ws['B3'].fill = Ok_couleur
```

All i achieved is to color one cell but i want to color all cell with Alexandre.

In this line I trie to replace the B3 with B without success:

```
for column in ws['B']:
        if column.value == "Alexandre":
            ws['B'].fill = Ok_couleur`
```

I also trie with B:B or B1:B5 and all i get is  "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fill'"

Comment: The index can be an Excel range. Try `B:B` or `B1:B5`. Another possibility is to [define a table](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worksheet_tables.html) and use one of the predefined table styles.

Comment: That doesn't work it say me "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fill'"